# How to find a group of elements in same Class not in the same Div in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am unaware of how to identify the elements in a same class however the div of each element differs

Comment: Can you post your HTML here and give an example of what exactly you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

Get all the elements under `tag` with `class` as 'classname' but different '`div`' s below:

```
  List<WebElement> elements= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//<tag>[@class='classname']/div"));
```

Comment: However i am having dynamic fields that to i need to find by text not by index

Answer (score 0):

Simply use syntax,
List  classele = driver.finElements(By.className("Paste your class name here"));

Import java.utils for List.
Import selenium class for WebElement.
copy paste class name from html tags of web page in "  ".
use for each loop or iterator to access List elements, you might need to use extra inbuilt method to fetch data like getText(),etc

Comment: I want to access particular or a single field in it